# Where is my mistake , web-pack babel eror

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

I have a issue , i wasted so much time on googling i need to ask here [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKjRO.png)

```
 var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path: require('path').resolve("./ReactApp/js"),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      publicPath: 'http://127.0.0.1:2992/js'
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }

      ]
   }

}

module.exports = config;
```

i don't know where is the issue , i just want learn React.js and this is preventing me to do it , can you please explain to me where is the mistake? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the text of your error message directly, not a link to an image of text.

Comment: Also post your package.json file. Edit both the error and the package.json into the question, don't post them in a comment.

Comment: It seems you have forgotten to install `babel-loader`. Try `npm install --save-dev babel-loader`

Comment: Use https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app to bootstrap ur app it s working out of the box

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out most probable you have not installed `babel-loader` module, so you need to do it via `npm install` command. Also, I would recommend to choose some react application generator which will setup the development environment for you to start learning React and not spend time fixing Webpack and other issue. The most simple one from my point of view is `create-react-app`.